# creation on stub/proxy classes from wsdl at compilation time

Tags: web-services, grails, java-metro-framework

Is it possible to include the wsdl in project and generate stub automatically at the time of project compilation?
I'm using grails, and grails-metro plugin for web services.

Comment: Instead of generating stubs separate and include in project manually, i want to generate the stubs project itself at the time of compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following method in grails gant script class.
    com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport.doMain(attrs)